# Filter array of objects by array of ids

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object

I have an array `activeIds` of ids of services and there is another array `servicesList` which contains objects of services.

Example: -

```
activeIds = [202, 204]
serviceList = [{  
                "id":201,
                "title":"a"
               },
               {  
                "id":202,
                "title":"a"
               },
               {  
                "id":203,
                "title":"c"
               },
               {  
                "id":204,
                "title":"d"
               },
               {  
                "id":205,
                "title":"e"
               }];
```

I want all the services(obj) whose ids are not a part of the first array i.e., `activeIds`. From the above example code **I want service obj of ids 201,203,205**

Final output -

```
expectedArray = [{  
                "id":201,
                "title":"a"
               },
               {  
                "id":203,
                "title":"c"
               },
               {  
                "id":205,
                "title":"e"
               }];
```

Here is my attempt to code. But it is not correct at all. Please help-

```
    const activeIds = e; // [202, 204]
    const obj = [];
    this.serviceList.map((s: IService) => {
        activeIds.map((id: number) => {
            if (id !== s.id) {
                obj.push(s);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: If the id array is long i suggest that you convert it to an object lookup or a map to avoid linear searching through the array for each element. Otherwise using the array.filter function is the way to go like suggested in every answer below.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can simply use **[`array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** with **[`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)** to check the matching element in the next array.

```
var arr = serviceList.filter(item => activeIds.indexOf(item.id) === -1);
```

**DEMO**

```js
let activeIds = [202, 204]
let serviceList = [{  
                "id":201,
                "title":"a"
               },
               {  
                "id":202,
                "title":"a"
               },
               {  
                "id":203,
                "title":"c"
               },
               {  
                "id":204,
                "title":"d"
               },
               {  
                "id":205,
                "title":"e"
               }];


let  arr = serviceList.filter(function(item){
      return activeIds.indexOf(item.id) === -1;
    });
    
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: How is the performance of this if `serviceList` is really huge?

Answer (score 27):

You can do this with `filter` and `includes` methods.

```js
const activeIds = [202, 204]
const serviceList = [{"id":201,"title":"a"},{"id":202,"title":"a"},{"id":203,"title":"c"},{"id":204,"title":"d"},{"id":205,"title":"e"}]

const result = serviceList.filter(({id}) => !activeIds.includes(id));
console.log(result)
```

Comment: op uses arrow function, why should not include work?

Comment: initially he did not had that in question! or i might have missed :(

Comment: Nice, I needed the opposite one, but just leaving out the ! in front of `activeIds` was my solution. Take your upvote sir!

Answer (score 4):

Use `filter` & `indexOf` method.`indexOf` will check if the current id is present in `activeIds` array

```js
var activeIds = [202, 204]
var serviceList = [{
    "id": 201,
    "title": "a"
  },
  {
    "id": 202,
    "title": "a"
  },
  {
    "id": 203,
    "title": "c"
  },
  {
    "id": 204,
    "title": "d"
  },
  {
    "id": 205,
    "title": "e"
  }
];

var filteredArray = serviceList.filter(function(item) {
  return activeIds.indexOf(item.id) === -1

});

console.log(filteredArray)
```

Comment: is not the same posted above

Comment: I have same doubt.Seems we posted almost at same time

Answer (score 2):

you can combine `indexOf` to check if the current id is on the active array and filter the array.