# How to filter/search for multiple keys in an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a dynamic array whose length keeps changing

Ex: `let array = [1,2]`

I have an array of objects, whose length also keeps changing:

```
let obj = [
  {id: 1, value: abc, location: xyz},
  {id: 2, value: pqr, location: xyz},
  {id: 3, value: rqp, location: xyz}
]
```

I want to return a final array of objects which has the id of "array" in "obj" i.e

```
[
  {id: 1, value: abc, location: xyz},
  {id: 2, value: pqr, location: xyz}
]
```

Does filter work in this case?

Comment: *"Does filter work in this case?"* Yes, certainly. Just see if the `id` of the object passed to your callback is in `array`.

Comment: duplicate: [Filter array of objects by array of ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48844452/filter-array-of-objects-by-array-of-ids)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter` and `Array.prototype.includes` for this.

```
obj.filter((item) => array.includes(item.id))
```